# Select greater than ORACLE

Tags: oracle

I've tried different variations of the following statement, the result is half of what it must do, I dont know what's missing.

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) AS NO_RESERVATIONS, HG.RESV_ID, HR.BOOKING_CUS_ID AS BOOKED_BY, C.CUS_NAME
FROM HOLIDAY_RESERVATION HR INNER JOIN(HOLIDAY_GROUP HG INNER JOIN CUSTOMER C
ON HG.CUS_ID = C.CUS_ID)
ON HR.BOOKING_CUS_ID = HG.CUS_ID
WHERE HR.RESV_ID >= 2
GROUP BY HG.RESV_ID, HR.BOOKING_CUS_ID, C.CUS_NAME;
```

**Yields**

```
NO_RESERVATIONS    RESV_ID  BOOKED_BY CUS_NAME
--------------- ---------- ---------- --------------------
              1          3          5 Beatrice P. Rosa
              1          8         15 Phillip B. Fleming
              1          7         13 Debra V. Key
              1          4          7 Magee A. Pace
              2         11          3 Hadassah T. Hebert
              1          5          9 Portia D. Melton
              2          2          3 Hadassah T. Hebert
              1          6         11 Larissa X. Boyer
              1          9         17 Wayne F. Burnett
              1         10         19 Eleanor J. Padilla

10 rows selected.
```

It should only show the person who has made two or more reservations, in this case *Hadassah T. Hebert*

**ANSWER** *Thanks Brian for the help*

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.CUS_NAME AS BOOKED_BY, COUNT(*) AS NO_RESERVATIONS
FROM HOLIDAY_RESERVATION HR INNER JOIN(HOLIDAY_GROUP HG INNER JOIN CUSTOMER C
ON HG.CUS_ID = C.CUS_ID)
ON HR.BOOKING_CUS_ID = HG.CUS_ID
GROUP BY HG.RESV_ID, HR.BOOKING_CUS_ID, C.CUS_NAME
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

*Yields*

```
BOOKED_BY            NO_RESERVATIONS
-------------------- ---------------
Hadassah T. Hebert                 2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To filter out grouped results, you need to use the HAVING statement.  So for your example, your query would look like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) AS NO_RESERVATIONS, HG.RESV_ID, HR.BOOKING_CUS_ID AS BOOKED_BY, C.CUS_NAME
FROM HOLIDAY_RESERVATION HR INNER JOIN(HOLIDAY_GROUP HG INNER JOIN CUSTOMER C
ON HG.CUS_ID = C.CUS_ID)
ON HR.BOOKING_CUS_ID = HG.CUS_ID
WHERE HR.RESV_ID >= 2
GROUP BY HG.RESV_ID, HR.BOOKING_CUS_ID, C.CUS_NAME
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Thanks very much, i shall never forget this :)